# Android HighChart, Get the Clicked Node In TreeMap

Tags: android, charts, highcharts

I have a treemap with a lot of nodes. When one of these nodes is clicked I want to be able to intercept and get the info about clicked node (id to be specific), instead of letting it drill down to next level.
The documentation/samples seems to be really outdated, I saw that in the latest version I can use

```
HIPlotOptions plotOptions = new HIPlotOptions();
plotOptions.setTreemap(myTreemap);
plotOptions.getTreemap().setInteractByLeaf(false);
plotOptions.getTreemap().allowTraversing.ççTree(true);
plotOptions.getTreemap().setLevelIsConstant(false);
plotOptions.getTreemap().setEvents(new HIEvents().setClick();
```

Now setClick takes HIFunction as an argument (version 10.3.2) but from there on out I am lost. How do I define it so that I have an onClickListener that gives me the id of the selected node?

Comment: Hi, I forwarded your question to the Highcharts Android expert, and I'll back with the answer as soon as possible. Regards!

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, this is not possible to achieve - the methods that take arguments in JS are not supported. Regards!